# Reasons why a CSS class does not get applied?

Tags: css, html

The following is my HTML structure

```
<div class="dxgroup rest_table_container">
  <table>....</table>
<div>
```

I have defined the following classes in my CSS file

```
rest_table_container 
rest_table_container th 
rest_table_container th label
rest_table_container td
rest_table_container input etc
```

My problem is that the class rest_table_container is not getting applied for the div that I have shown in the HTML. dxgroup class which is present in the same CSS file is getting applied. Also all the classes I have defined based on the class rest_table_container like "rest_table_container input" are all getting applied for the corresponding elements.

Comment: Can you post the actual CSS? The example you gave is missing periods and commas, so maybe there's just a typo somewhere.

Comment: Are you sure there are no other CSS conflicts? We need more info. Check out firebug for debugging CSS/HTML with firefox, developers tools for ie etc.

Comment: Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ from it? Or can you check this, because it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/HAPEC/

Comment: Agreed, post the actual CSS. Better yet, link to the full CSS file since the problem might reside in your other code (overwriting the styling or resetting it).

Answer (score 0):

if that's a direct copy of your CSS classes, the problem is clear as day. You have to use a period in front of your class names.

```
.class-name

#idName
```

There is also a certain amount of oddities when it comes to styling tables with CSS. For example, if you're trying to give padding or margin to a TR, you can't do that, only can you do it on a TD. There are other caveats, but seeing your code will provide the best answer.